# Finding Daily Max and Min values in Google Spreadsheet array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, max, min

I need to pick the daily minimum and maximum values out of a growing array of temperature recordings like this:

Date and Time  Temperature deg C

..

20/1/2017 10:05      0.3

20/1/2017 11:08      0.4

..

so the result would look like this:

Date          Min temp   Max temp

20/1/2017     -0.5       2.2

21/1/2017     -0.3       3.0

...

I was able to extract the data of a specific day using =FILTER (range, date criterion), but finding the Min and Max values for all the dates in the array eludes me. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try query:

```
=QUERY({A:B},"select Col1, max(Col2), min(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1")
```

[image]

how it works:

1. `{A:B}` use curly brackets to convert range into array. Now query may contain Col1, Col2, etc...
2. `select Col1, max(Col2), min(Col2) ... group by Col1` use to make aggregate functions
3. `where Col1 is not null` so when use open range `A:B` to eliminate blanks.

Comment: Hello! Thanks, but I found a problem: The date values include times, e.g. 20/1/2017 11:38. It appears the formula only aggregates those rows with equal values e.g. 20/1/2017.
However, I can work around this by truncating the values in the date column, or reformatting it to date only