# Finding the daily max (and its domain) fails in spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761625/finding-daily-max-and-min-values-in-google-spreadsheet-array) I have tried the same, but got an error:

I would like to get the daily max for each date, and the domain name who got this score.

```
=query({A8:C}, "select todate(A), B, max(C), where A is not null group by todate(A) order by todate(A) asc")
```

also

```
=query(A8:C, "select todate(A), B, max(C), where A is not null group by todate(A) order by todate(A) asc", 0)
")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first formula:

- because of the array {} you'll have to use numeric column reference
- include the second column in the group by

See it this helps

```
=query({A3:C}, "select todate(Col1), Col2, max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by todate(Col1), Col2 order by todate(Col1) asc label todate(Col1)'', Col2 '', max(Col3)''")
```

For your second formula:

- include column B in the group by

Try

```
=query(A3:C, "select todate(A), B, max(C) where A is not null group by todate(A), B order by todate(A) asc label todate(A)'', B '', max(C)''")
```

Note:

- I also added a label-clause to get rid of the headers caused by the aggregation.
- Depending on your locale, you have to a semi-colon after the range instead of a comma.

---

### EDIT

If you want to see which domain name got the highest score per day, you can try

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(sort(unique(A3:A)), sort(A3:C, 3, 0), {1, 2, 3}, 0)))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
I would like to get the daily max for each date, and the domain name who got this score.

Comment: I also added a label-clause to get rid of the headers caused by the aggregation.
But if I skip the last `[headers]` arg and exclude the headers from the range - that's not enough?

Comment: `Depending on your locale, you have to a semi-colon after the range instead of a comma.`

Sorry to ask, but which part do you referrer to ? I see no semicolon

Comment: OMG, that seems complex. I'm not sure I know what vlookup over 2 queries mean. Nevertheless it worked. I understand the vlookup over one query. I  will have to think again why two queries are needed

Comment: Some locales use semi-colons instead of commas as argument separators in formulae.

Comment: I removed the double query() in favor of a simple sort(). ;-)